# Orthogonal complement on $L^2[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality

**Problem:** Consider the Hilbert space $L^2[0,1]$ and the set $S=\{p(x): p(x) \text{is polynomial such that }p(0)=0 \rbrace$. Find the orthogonal complement of $S$, that is, $S^{\perp}$.

My idea is: Consider the orthonormal basis $\{e^{2n\pi ix}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ therefore, $\forall f \in L^2[0,1]$ we have $f(x)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\tilde{f}(k)e^{2k\pi ix}$ where $\tilde{f}(k)= \int_0^1 f(x)e^{-2k \pi ix}dx$.

For $p(x) \in S$ we have that $p(0)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\tilde{p}(k)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 p(x)e^{-2k \pi ix}dx=\int_0^1\frac{p(x)e^{2\pi x}}{e^{2\pi x}-1}dx=0$. Now, for $f(x) \in L^2[0,1]$ fixed $$\langle p(x),f(x) \rangle = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\tilde{p}(k) \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \tilde{f}(m) \langle e_k,e_m \rangle= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\tilde{p}(k)\tilde{f}(k)$$
So, $$S^{\perp}=\{f(x) \in L^2: \langle p(x), f(x)\rangle=0, \quad \forall p(x) \in S\}$$
$$S^{\perp}=\{f(x) \in L^2:\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\tilde{p}(k)\tilde{f}(k)=0, \quad \forall p(x) \in S\}$$.

I don't now how be explicit in this set $S^{\perp}$. Any solution?

Comment: The Fourier basis isn't a useful basis here, since it doesn't have very much to do with polynomials. Try applying Stone-Weierstrass or thinking about orthogonal polynomials instead.

Comment: Try showing that $S$ is dense in $L^2$. What does this tell you?

Comment: @PhoemueX this is true? What about with the constants?

Comment: Try guessing first.

Comment: @copper.hat I think that is not dense, because the set $\{x^i:i >0\}$ is a basis for $S$ and this is not dense for the constants.

Comment: Consider continuous functions first and show that you can find an arbitrarily close polynomial that passes through zero.

Comment: @Asar This is the $L^2$ norm, not $L^\infty$. You can find a polynomial that passes through zero and is arbitrarily close to any constant you want.

Comment: Constants are not in the orthogonal complement.  $S$ is dense.

Comment: @geetha290krm You can help me to prove this statement?

Comment: Why don't you read my comment and try that first. If constants are in the closure of $S$ then it doesn't leave much room for a non trivial complement.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks, I will try!

Comment: Apply the Weierstrass theorem to show that the polynomials such that $p(0)=0$ are uniformly  dense in $C_0[0,1]$ the continuous functions vanishing at $0.$ Then show that $C_0[0,1]$ is dense in $L^2(0,1).$